# css style tag is not working

Tags: html, css

I was trying to set the image in the background using the following code but the output comes out to be blank . please help!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hotel Registration form</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-image: url(file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/WE/Pics/prac6/resort.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `file://` URIs are notoriously iffy. Use a relative URI instead.

Comment: Use a relative path for the image. For instance, if the image is in the same folder as the html, it would just be `background-image: url(resort.jpg);`

Comment: @guneet use relative url of image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative path. As well create a project folder and make an order for your project. then it is really easy.

- Project

  - folders (css/images/js/etc...)
  - main files (index/about/etc....)

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Hotel Registration form</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background-image: url(img/resort.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```